# My character hangs in the air in the game I made in the unity game engine

Tags: unity-game-engine

if my character runs towards the wall, he gets stuck in the wall and hangs in the air. why doesn't gravity pull him down? Is it a bug in the code or did I make a mistake in physics?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/930dC.png)

to fall to the ground

Comment: please provide [mcve] instructions.. otherwise its hard to help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing I can think of is that your walls are tagged - or set to the same layer - as your ground. Because of this, when your character is airborne and touches a wall, isGrounded is set to true.
If you are using a CharacterController, you can easily check this in the Inspector during runtime (you might need the DebugView mode since I haven't used CharControllers in a while). Another option would be to log isGrounded to the console.

Let me know if this helps!